# Cannot pass secure and sameSite cookie options with token with Apollo-Server-Express

Tags: express, cookies, graphql, apollo-server

I'm having trouble attaching the secure and sameSite option to my auth token on my signin mutation. It works just fine if I remove the two options and only send httpOnly and maxAge. I'm using Apollo-Server-Express which to my understanding includes Express.js.

Sorry for the dump, but frankly I'm at a loss here. My setup -

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });
const createServer = require("./createServer");
const db = require("./db");

const server = createServer();
const app = express();

// Use express middleware to handle cookies (JWT)
app.use(cookieParser());

// decode JQT so we can get userId on each request
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    // put user Id onto the request for future requetss to access
    req.userId = userId;
  }

  next();
});

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  // if they aren't logged in, skip this
  if (!req.userId) return next();
  const member = await db.query.member(
    { where: { id: req.userId } },
    "{ id, permissions, email, name }"
  );
  req.member = member;

  next();
});

// start it!
server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  // Commenting this out breaks CORS
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
  },
});

app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)
);
```

createServer.js

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server-express");

const Mutation = require("./resolvers/Mutation");
const Query = require("./resolvers/Query");
const db = require("./db");

const { importSchema } = require("graphql-import");
const typeDefsFile = importSchema(__dirname.concat("/schema.graphql"));
const typeDefs = gql(typeDefsFile);

function createServer() {
  return new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: gql`
      ${typeDefs}
    `,

    context: (req) => ({ ...req, db }),
    resolverValidationOptions: {
      requireResolversForResolveType: false,
    },
    resolvers: {
      Mutation,
      Query,
    },
  });
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

Signin mutation

```
  async signin(parent, { email, password }, ctx, info) {
    // 1. check if member with that email exists
    const member = await ctx.db.query.member({ where: { email } });
    if (!member) {
      throw new Error(`No member found for email ${email}`);
    }

    // 2. check password is correct
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, member.password);
    if (!valid) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid Password`);
    }

    // 3. create JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: member.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET);

    // 4. set the cookie
    ctx.res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // 1 year cookie
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    });

    // 5. return the member
    return member;
  },
```

Package.JSON (was running GraphQL Yoga prior)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.16.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.16.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-samesite-default": "^1.0.6",
    "graphql": "^14.0.0",
    "graphql-cli": "^2.17.0",
    "graphql-import": "^1.0.2",
    "graphql-yoga": "1.16.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prisma": "1.17.1",
    "prisma-binding": "2.1.6",
    "stripe": "^6.12.1"
  },
```

Comment: Also, I have credentials set to include on my Apollo Client

Comment: So the secure flag not working is because I'm on localhost and so true would expect https. Setting that to false allows the cookie to be set. But sameSite none is still not working. Is it possible that sameSite is being impacted because I'm on localhost? I'm using Docker and I believe that self-resolves the issue but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, this does appear to be a localhost kind of issue. Console is spitting this out: A cookie associated with a resource at http://localhost/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. So I think if I push this up to my stg environment it should work.